# iAd banner shows empty black space after dismissing modal view

Tags: ios, uitableview, iad, uistoryboardsegue, candisplaybannerads

My app shows banner ads at the bottom of `UIViewController` which is root view using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` in `viewDidLoad()`. App has a settings view which is a `UITableViewController` and i am showing the ads there as well in the same way.

When i dismiss the modal view (settings view/table view) the banner ads on root view `UIViewController` goes away and shows a black rectangular box where iAd banner is supposed to display.

The dismiss action/done button on modal view is a unwind to exit() segue.

I am suspecting it is something to do with modal presentation - `over full screen` or dismiss action i.e. unwind to exit() segue.

**EDIT** -  Just to validate, I tried various presentation styles for modal view and segue back from settings scene to view scene and it worked. But doesn't work the way i am showing table view/settings page as modal view presentation  `over full screen`

I did some more research but many posts suggest that reason behind as constraints/limitation of using iAd with `UITableViewController`

I could not identify any details about using iAd with `UITableViewController` so far. Need help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` to your `viewDidAppear()` for each view controller.

Comment: Didn't work. Ad banner never loads. Also, it breaks auto-layout constraints & the view on landscape orientation (the app has different orientations supported)